# Filter in List with condition in the object

Tags: java, filter, java-stream

I have a List.
Employee, for example:

```
@Data
@AllArgConstructor
public class Employee {
 
   private string firstName;
   private string last name;
   private domestic salary;
   private LocalDataTime getSalary;

}
```

The sheet can contain data with the same last name, first name, but different date and salary.
Or maybe not. For example.

```
List<Employee> employee = new ArrayList<>();
Employee one = new Employee("John", "Smith", 10, 2022-09-01);
Employee two = new Employee("John", "Smith", 20, 2022-10-01);
Employee three = new Employee("John", "Smith", 5, 2022-11-01);
Employee four = new Employee("Kelly", "Jones", 12, 2022-03-01);
Employee five = new Employee("Sara", "Kim", 21, 2022-03-01);
Employee six = new Employee("Sara", "Kim", 7, 2022-07-01);

employee.add(one);
employee.add(two);
employee.add(three);
employee.add(four);
employee.add(five);
employee.add(six);
```

Need for each unique combination of last name and first name, get a data for the last date.

In Out:

"John", "Smith", 5, 2022-11-01

"Kelly", "Jones", 12, 2022-03-01

"Sara", "Kim", 7, 2022-07-01

I'm just starting to learn stream API and dont understand how to filter by a field inside an object for 2 unique other fields.

Is it possible to do so?

Comment: Please, share your **attempt** and specify the problem you've encountered. Every question on StackOverflow is expected to demonstrate an effort. See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Comment: I am very ashamed, but my decisions were far from the truth. Thanks for the comment. I won't ask any more questions without a partial solution

Comment: Don't beat yourself up, we're all learning here on SO :) Don't hesitate to post more questions here, but it's true that it is good to remember that people appreciate questions more when they can see that you've given it a good attempt yourself :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use collect toMap, the key should be the firstName and lastName, I put them in a list(There are other ways for example concatenate the two attributes, but I don't recommend it), and then use the `BinaryOperator` to retrieve the max date:

```
Collection<Employee> response = employee.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(
               e -> e.getFirstName()+e.getLastName(),
               Function.identity(),
               (e1, e2) -> e1.getDate().isAfter(e2.getDate()) ? e1 : e2)).values();
```

Outputs:

```
Employee(firstName=John, lastName=Smith, salary=5, date=2022-11-01)
Employee(firstName=Sara, lastName=Kim, salary=7, date=2022-07-01)
Employee(firstName=Kelly, lastName=Jones, salary=12, date=2022-03-01)
```

Answer (score 0):

My idea is to create hashmap as `HashMap<List<String>>,Employee>` on top of Stream.  Then do merge operation on hashmap. Maps key is list of first_name & last_name:

```
HashMap<List<String>,Employee> map = 
    employee.stream().collect(HashMap<List<String>, Employee>::new,
                                    (x, y) -> x.merge(List.of(y.getFirstName(), y.getLast_name()), y,
                                            (a, b) -> a.getGetSalary().isAfter(b.getGetSalary()) ? a : b),
                                    (p, q) -> p.putAll(q));

System.out.println(map.values());
```

This will give you desired result. `employee` is list which you created in your original post.